# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException while adding elements?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have a servlet which uses a service to parse a `YAML` file. but when I put some user traffic on my servlet I get:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [SitesController] in context with path [] threw exception [java.util.ConcurrentModificationException] with root cause
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1129)
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.listIterator(ArrayList.java:1009)
    ...
    at com.example.UrlRedirectEngin.redirectoToRespectiveSubDomain(UrlRedirectEngin.java:250)
```

I am not sure if the exception is from parsing the YAML file or not. However the exception is pointing to the line below which I render the page `line 250:`

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(JSP_PAGE).forward(request, response);
```

I just want to know if `ConcurrentModificationException` can also happens while adding elements to a `Map`?
If yes how can I handle this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show in which line the exception occurs?

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach: yeah, you can see the line in the post.

Comment: @tokhi Ican only see lines from within the ArrayList class. In your code, there is only one ArralyList visible. That list is not modified by your code and cannot throw this exception. I yould need the linenumber of YOUR code (and the code)

Comment: If you down vote the question please also write the reason. thanks.

Comment: UrlRedirectEngin line number 250 is which one?

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach: this line: `request.getRequestDispatcher(JSP_PAGE).forward(request, response);`

Comment: I think you are missing some important parts in your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52132/discussion-between-christian-kuetbach-and-tokhi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(JSP_PAGE).forward(request, response);
```

forwards to an JSP page. The error may be inside  of that JSP as well (the part of the stacktrace may hide the original error)

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentModificationException means that you are editing your map/collection when you try to read it.
Simple example :

```
final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>()
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; {
        {
            add("Hi");
            add("This is a test");
        }
    };
for(final String string : list) {
    if(string.equals("Hi")) {
        list.remove("Hi");
    }
}
```

I think getRequestDispatcher is modifying your map while your using it.

Comment: but I'm not removing anything

Comment: But maybe you are changing some things.